# Having trouble connecting to home network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

Ok so my laptop has recently (in the past month) started having trouble connecting to the home network. It will intermittently connect and disconnect every time I log on to my laptop. It will last for the entire session, but next time I turn on my laptop I don't know if I'll have internet again.

I have even tried working around this by using an Ethernet cable, but that's still just as bad.

At first I thought it was the network card, but at no point did it ever stop picking up networks, just my own. It can't be the router either, because I am the only one in the house that has these connection issues (we have multiple PCs, consoles and mobile devices).

Can anyone tell me what's going on?

EDIT: I'm still using windows 7, it's a few years old, but I'm pretty sure all the drivers are up to date.

Comment: There isn't enough information here to be able to offer definitive help. [Edit] your question with more details so someone can help you. What OS are you using? When did this start happening? What have you attempted to fix this so far? Are all drivers updated? Is the system clean of viruses and malware? Etc...ect...ect...

Comment: Check to make sure your Windows 7 machine doesn't have a static IP that conflicts with another device on your LAN. You MAY have some malware on your machine that is causing the connect/reconnect problem. Do you have an Internet security package installed that has an over-zealous firewall?

Comment: @BigChris I have AVG and Malwarebytes, but I've had them for ages and never had any troubles. As for the ip stuff I don't know much about that...